# ASP.NET MVC - View with multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I am trying to generate such HTML

```
    <form action="/some/process" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="foo.a" value="aaa"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="bar.b" value="bbb"/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

so it can be processed by this Action:

```
    public ActionResult Process(Foo foo, Bar bar)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Given the Action code

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        ViewData["foo"] = new Foo { A = "aaa" };
        ViewData["bar"] = new Bar { B = "bbb" };

        return View();
    }
```

what should I write in Edit.aspx view? I don't want to write names 'foo.a' and 'bar.b' manually.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

String-indexed `ViewData` is bad. What you probably want to do is make a little wrapper class for your multi-variable view data and pass that to a strongly typed view. IE:

```
public class FooBarViewData
{
   public Foo Foo {get; set;}
   public Bar Bar {get; set;}
}
public ActionResult Edit()
{
   FooBarViewData fbvd = new FooBarViewData();
   fbvd.Foo = new Foo(){ A = "aaa"};
   fbvd.Bar = new Bar(){ B = "bbb"};
   return View(fbvd);
}
```

Then your view is just strongly typed to `FooBarViewData` and you can call members of that object using the `Model` property.

Answer (score 11):

You have a couple of choices.  First, you can reference them from ViewData and use an HtmlHelper extension. Or you could create a view-specific model and use a strongly-typed viewpage for Edit.aspx.

```
public class EditModel
{
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
    public Bar bar { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var model = new EditModel();

    model.foo = new Foo { A = "aaa" };
    model.bar = new Bar { B = "bbb" };

    return View( model );
}
```

(Edit.aspx is of type `ViewPage<EditModel>`)

Either way, the HtmlHelper extension will pick up any initial values.

```
<form action="/some/process" method="post">
     <%= Html.Hidden( "foo.A" ) %>
     <%= Html.Hidden( "bar.B" ) %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above may be outdated. This solution seems to work for ASP.Net MVC5+.

You're going to have to use the `ViewModel` method. This is an excellent tutorial that you can check out.

http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/how-to-use-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example

You are going to have to join multiple models into one `ViewModel` and grab all the properties from each models you want to use into the `ViewModel`.

***BUT***, it is *HIGHLY* advised that you create a new *Controller* and a new *View* to accomodate the newly created `ViewModel`. Read the tutorial.

```
public class FooBarViewModel
{
   public string A {get; set;}  //Property for Foo
   public string B {get; set;}  //Property for Bar
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
   FooBarViewModel fooBarVM = new FooBarViewModel();
   fooBarVM.A = "aaa";
   fooBarVM.B = "bbb";

   return View(fooBarVM);
}
```

But in this case, you should be able to pass the `ViewModel` into a different view. Just make sure you declare this similar directive correctly in the `foobar.cshtml` page.

```
@model FooBar.Models.FooBarViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling for a while trying to get two models to work, and most of the answers I came across was meant for earlier versions of MVC.

I found the following tutorial works best for MVC 5 as suggested by **David Lee**:

http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/how-to-use-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example

I created a join and selected only the columns I needed from both Models.

I had it working with partial views

In view.cshtml

```
 @model IEnumerable<Test.Models.TestViewModel>
    ...
      @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TestName)
...
```