# Need to map from two objects into a single one

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following entity model:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    // more attributes here...
}
```

I would like to prepare a view model (specific for my view). Here is the view model:

```
public class ProjectListViewModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<ProjectInfos> ProjectList { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo Paging { get; set; }

    public class ProjectInfos
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public int    Year { get; set; }
    }

    public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller, I would like to prepare the view model by filling it with 2 different objects:

1. List of projects
2. Paging information

Here is my controller:

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
{
    IEnumerable<Project> projectList = m_Business.GetProjects(category, page, 10);
    PagingInfo pagingInfo = m_Business.GetPagingInfo(category, page, 10);

    // Here I need to map !!
    ProjectListViewModel viewModel = .....

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So how can I proceed in my controller? I know we can use automapper to map from one object to another **but here I need to map from two objects into a single one.**

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle view model with multiple aggregate roots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020499/how-to-handle-view-model-with-multiple-aggregate-roots)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend AutoMapper to map multiple objects.

[Here is a blog](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx) which provides some sample cope.

Then you can use code like this:

```
 var personViewModel = EntityMapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(person, address, comment);
```

Comment: @Darin: Thanks but is it possible to have nested classes in the view model like in my question? I downloaded example provided in the blog and try to adapt with one nested class and try to Map but it failed.

Comment: @Darin: I mean, let's take a look at the blog provided in the url, in the example, his view model class contains some attributes (all at the same level) but no nested class. I would like a solution where my view model contains objects. Thanks.

Comment: @Bronzato Mapping a nested class is possible with AutoMapper. Have a look at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening As you can see, you can use a default configuration (Order.Customer.Name => CustomerName) or you can configure it yourself with Mapper.CreateMap<,>.ForMember(..)