# MVC multiple data-models passed to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC - View with multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944334/asp-net-mvc-view-with-multiple-models)

Using ASP.NET MVC 3.0, how can I pass multiple data models from my controller to my view?  I'm hoping for an elegant solution...thanks!

BTW - I can provide code samples but I think this is generic enough not to warrant it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a truly elegant way to do it, unfortunately.  My preferred method is to encapsulate the two objects and send that to the view.

```
public class City{
public Mall TheMall;
public School TheSchool;
}
```

Then your view will be strongly typed as City, and you will use `Model.TheMall.Property` and `Model.TheSchool.Property` to access what you need.

Another method is to use the ViewData bag.  What you can do is populate it like such:

```
ViewData["City"] = "Toronto";  //random string
ViewData["Mall"] = new TheMall(...);
return View(MyViewName);
```

And then in your view, you will have access these using the key you assigned in the controller ("City", "Mall", in this case).

Hope that helps!

Comment: The first method is pretty commonly known as a ViewModel, and usually people will have a ViewModels folder to hold these, separate from the Models folder.  I personally call the ModelProjections because it is essentially a layer of abstraction that allows you to compose projections of your model specialized for your UI.