# Executing different queries that go into the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to deliver content from different queries to the view from a single controller action method.

Currently, I have controller and I fire two queries on same table, first take students who are in 8 std and second who are in 9 std:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    private MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = db.table1.where(t => t.Class_ID == 8);
        var query2 = db.table1.where(t => t.Class_ID == 9);
        return View(query1, query2));
    }
}
```

Then I want to display query1 and query2 data on a Index view of Student controller.
Please help me. Thanking for all replies

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - View with multiple models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944334/asp-net-mvc-view-with-multiple-models)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action build and pass this view model to the view:

```
var model1 = (from r in db.content...)
var model2 = (from r in db.content...)
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.Model1 = model1;
viewModel.Model2 = model2;
return View(viewModel);
```

Now your view will be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and you will be able to access its properties:

```
@Model.Model1.SomePropertyOfTheFirstModel
@Model.Model2.SomePropertyOfTheSecondModel
```

Comment: What if he want use it with different models?

Comment: You would then write another view model. Every view should have its own view model anyways. Having `Model1` and `Model2` as property names is not good in any case. You should use specialized view models.

Answer (score 3):

Create class that names `ViewModels` with two properties, like this:

```
public class ViewModels<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller create instance of `ViewModels` and pass it to the view:

```
var viewModels= new ViewModels<Model1, Model2>() { Model1 = model1, Model2 = model2 };
return View(viewModels);
```

Now on the  view use:

```
@model ViewModels<Model1, Model2>
@Model.Model1.PropertyOfModel1
@Model.Model2.PropertyOfModel2
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new `ViewModel` class which will have your data required for that view,populate that `ViewModel` object by data and pass it on to View

example

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
  //member of type model1
  //member of type model2
}
```